# execute command setblock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok so when you throw a snowball I have

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:ice'
```

So this makes an ice path following under the snowball. I had some code something like this and it worked but I modified it and accidently broke it. So what is the correct code that I originally had that made this work? I also tried everything like  `/execute @e[type=Snowball] /setblock minecraft:ice ~ ~-1 ~` and

`/execute ~ ~-1 ~ @e[type=Snowball] /setblock minecraft:ice` 
last one I tried was `/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~-1 ~  /setblock minecraft:ice`

Comment: This is in a command block (presumably triggered by a fill clock)?  You don't need the `/` for command blocks, and actually, I think it might screw things up for the execute.

Comment: Also, [here's the command documentation](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#execute)

Comment: Ok I'll try that and I used the '/' for execute maybe the '/' was screwing it up for setblock. I'll try it and thanks for the link of command documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ ice
```

I tested that and it works perfectly fine. I think you do need that / in front of setblock for it to work.

Comment: `/` is unnecessary in a command block, it should work with or without. The error that you corrected is putting the execute coordinates in the right place.

Comment: What this fixes is including *both* sets of coordinates for the execute and for the setblock. All the examples in the question are missing one or the other set of coordinates. (And that is why cargo-cult programming is a bad idea…)

Answer (score -1):

```
execute @e[type=Snowball] setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:ice
```

In a command block, the leading `/` is unnecessary.

In the `/execute` command, there can't be a / before `setblock`

Comment: A `/` before `seblock` is fine. This won't work though, because you don't have the execute coordinates.